# Mergemap terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'

Tags: c++, genetic

I am running Mergemap tool to merge the two genetic maps. i downloaded the sample data and i m runing the merge map for the sample input data. it shows the following error

```
number of maps 8 
map0,   1.000,  lg_raw_map0
map1,   1.000,  lg_raw_map1
map2,   1.000,  lg_raw_map2
map3,   1.000,  lg_raw_map3
map4,   1.000,  lg_raw_map4
map5,   1.000,  lg_raw_map5
map6,   1.000,  lg_raw_map6
map7,   1.000,  lg_raw_map7
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Please anyone help to fix this

Comment: Show us the code, cannot *possibly* help you with a problem in your code unless we can see your code.

Comment: You ran out of memory. Maybe use less memory consuming algorithms and data structures. And of course make sure you free memory you don't use, means: use smart pointers.

Comment: @ArneMertz: Having 24 GB ram. . i dont think its running out of memory. code and input data is available at http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~yonghui/mgmap.html

Comment: Since it's not even your code I think you should contact the author.

Comment: i did but didnt got response. .

Comment: Well it's way too much code to go through on this forum I think. You should find someone who knows C++ and is prepared to spend some time debugging the code.

Comment: @Dadu `bad_alloc` means "could not allocate memory". having 24GB does not mean much - the OS won't give it all to you, and depending on your data structures and algorithms 24GB can run out pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I had accidentally misspelled one of the map names in one of my config files! So it could be a problem either with the map file names, or ability to read the maps mentioned in the config file in the first place. Hope you sorted it. ([MergeMap site](http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~yonghui/mgmap.html) )